# Underline button in toolbar is not updated when text is recovered from database to RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, database, format, richtextbox

I have a format toolbar for a RichTextBox.

XAML for Underline button: (rtb is the RichTextBox)

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="btnUnderline" Command="{x:Static EditingCommands.ToggleUnderline}" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=rtb}">
    <TextBlock Height="16" Width="16" Foreground="Black" Text="S" TextDecorations="Underline" TextAlignment="Center" />
</ToggleButton>
```

Code to update toolbar buttons state according with format of selected text:

```
private void UpdateToggleButtonState()
{
    UpdateItemCheckedState(btnBold, TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);
    UpdateItemCheckedState(btnItalic, TextElement.FontStyleProperty, FontStyles.Italic);
    UpdateItemCheckedState(btnUnderline, Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, TextDecorations.Underline);
    UpdateItemCheckedState(btnAlignLeft, Block.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Left);
    UpdateItemCheckedState(btnAlignCenter, Block.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Center);
    UpdateItemCheckedState(btnAlignRight, Block.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Right);
    UpdateItemCheckedState(btnAlignJustify, Block.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Justify);
}

private void UpdateItemCheckedState(ToggleButton button, DependencyProperty formattingProperty,
                                    object expectedValue)
{
    var currentValue = rtb.Selection.GetPropertyValue(formattingProperty);
    button.IsChecked = currentValue != null && currentValue != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue &&
                       currentValue.Equals(expectedValue);
}
```

Everything works fine after I just format text. For example, if I select some text and apply bold, italic and underline format and then select text without format in another place, the Bold, Italic and Underline buttons are deactivated and when I select the formatted text then the 3 buttons are activated again.

The problem is when I save and recover text from the database. Everything works fine except for the Underline button.

The recovered text really is underlined on screen but when I click on it or select it only the Bold and Italic buttons become activated. The Underline button remains deactivated.

This is the code to save the formatted text to database:

```
string rtfText; // string to save to database
var tr = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    tr.Save(ms, DataFormats.Rtf);
    rtfText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.ToArray());
}
```

And to recover the formatted text from database:

```
var rtfText = ... // string recovered from database
var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rtfText);

using (var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
{
    var tr = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
    tr.Load(ms, DataFormats.Rtf);
}
```

If I write the phrase "Some text." and apply bold, italic and underline format this is the string saved to database:

{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\htmautsp\deff2{\fonttbl{\f0\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f2\fcharset0 Segoe UI;}}{\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;}\loch\hich\dbch\pard\plain\ltrpar\itap0{\lang1033\fs18\f2\cf0 \cf0\ql{\f2 {\lang5130\b\i\ul\ltrch Some text.}\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}
}
}

Any help will be much appreciated.

**Edit**

In the UpdateItemCheckedState() method, currentValue.Equals(expectedValue) is the condition that fails. It's always false even when the selected text is underlined.

**Edit 2**

Now I'm using another code to generate the text that will be saved/recovered to/from database.

To save:

```
using (var sw = new StringWriter())
{
    XamlWriter.Save(rtb.Document, sw);
    rtfText = sw.ToString(); // string to save to database
}
```

To recover:

```
// rtfText is the string recovered from database
rtb.Document = XamlReader.Parse(rtfText) as FlowDocument;
```

For the phrase "Some text." with bold, italic and underline format the text in the database now is (after indenting):

```
<FlowDocument PagePadding="5,0,5,0" AllowDrop="True" NumberSubstitution.CultureSource="User" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Paragraph>
        <Run FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Bold" xml:lang="es-cr">
            <Run.TextDecorations>
                <TextDecoration Location="Underline" />
            </Run.TextDecorations>
            Some text.
        </Run>
    </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

That looks ok but the problem with the Underline button persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [msfanboy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252289/msfanboy)'s answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202434/get-fontweight-fontstyle-textdecorations-from-wpf-richtextbox) finally the Underline button is working as expected.

I did change the line:

```
UpdateItemCheckedState(btnUnderline, Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, TextDecorations.Underline);
```

with this one:

```
UpdateItemUnderlineState(); // To manage the special case
```

The UpdateItemUnderlineState() method is:

```
private void UpdateItemCheckedStateUnderline()
{
    var currentValue = rtb.Selection.GetPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty);
    TextDecorationCollection collection = null;

    if (currentValue is TextDecorationCollection && currentValue != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
    {
        collection = currentValue as TextDecorationCollection;
    }

    btnUnderline.IsChecked = collection != null && collection.Count > 0;
}
```

Thanks msfanboy!