# WPF RichTextbox hosted in Windows Forms : Tracking button state

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, formatting, toolbar

I've created a Windows Forms hosted WPF RichTextbox control.
It is based on the one posted by Brian Lagunas at [Elegant Code](http://elegantcode.com/2010/10/26/create-your-own-format-bar-for-the-wpf-richtextbox/).

It has worked well but recently an issue was reported and I've been unable to find the reason for it.
Brian does warn readers about dealing with button state, but I think I'm doing that fine.

Example:

**Provided the following text:**

*Paragraph 1*

*I turned off the Bold and Underline, and it appears to be working fine.
William Blake Richmond was born in 1842 in London. His father, George Richmond, R.A. (1809-1896), himself the son of Thomas Richmond, painted the portraits of the most eminent people of his day and played a part in society. He was named after a close friend of his father, the artist William Blake.*

If I highlight "Paragraph 1", press backspace, then enable 'bold' and 'underline' using the keyboard shortcuts, Ctrl+B and Ctrl+U, and start typing, the word will appear unformatted. The bold and underline buttons, on the toolbar also get unmarked\unchecked.

The following code blocks show the handling of the KeyUp event of the control, for the shortcuts.

```
private void RTFBox_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateButtonsStateBasedOnKeys(e);
}

private void UpdateButtonsStateBasedOnKeys(System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys.Control &&
    e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.B)
    {
        UpdateButtonsState(_ToolStrip.BoldButton);
    }
    else if (e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys.Control &&
             e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.U)
    {
        UpdateButtonsState(_ToolStrip.UnderlineButton);
    }
    // Removed other if blocks for brevity

    UpdateTextRangeFormattingState();
}

public void UpdateButtonsState(System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton button)
{
    //Other conditions removed
    UpdateButtonCheckedState(button);   
}

private void UpdateButtonCheckedState(System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton button)
{
    button.Checked = !button.Checked;
}

private void UpdateTextRangeFormattingState()
{
    UpdateTextRangeFormatting(_ToolStrip.BoldButton, TextElement.FontWeightProperty,     FontWeights.Bold, FontWeights.Regular);
    UpdateTextRangeFormatting(_ToolStrip.UnderlineButton, Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, TextDecorations.Underline, null);
    // Removed other statements for brevity
}

private void UpdateTextRangeFormatting(System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton button, DependencyProperty formattingProperty, object expectedValue, object oppositeValue)
{
    TextPointer position = _RTFBox.TextSelection.End;
    if (position != null)
    {
        TextRange range = new TextRange(position, _RTFBox.TextSelection.End);
        if (button.Checked)
        {
            range.ApplyPropertyValue(formattingProperty, expectedValue);
        }
        else
        {
            range.ApplyPropertyValue(formattingProperty, oppositeValue);
        }
    }
}
```

And the following blocks correspond to the selectionchanged event.

```
private void Box_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateButtonsStateWithSelection();
}

private void UpdateButtonsStateWithSelection()
{
    TextPointer position = _RTFBox.TextSelection.End.GetPositionAtOffset(-1);
    if (position != null)
    {
        TextRange range = new TextRange(position, _RTFBox.TextSelection.End);
        if (range.IsEmpty)
        {
            position = _RTFBox.TextSelection.End.GetPositionAtOffset(1);
            if (position != null)
            {
                range = new TextRange(position, _RTFBox.TextSelection.End);
            }
        }

        if (!range.IsEmpty)
        {
            UpdateAllButtonsCheckedState();
        }
    }
}

private void UpdateAllButtonsCheckedState()
{
    UpdateButtonCheckedState(_ToolStrip.BoldButton, TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold, FontWeights.Regular);     
    UpdateButtonCheckedState(_ToolStrip.UnderlineButton, Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, TextDecorations.Underline, null);
    // Other statements removed for brevity
}

private void UpdateButtonCheckedState(System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton button, DependencyProperty formattingProperty,
                                      object expectedValue, object oppositeValue)
{
    object value = _SpellBox.TextSelection.GetPropertyValue(formattingProperty);
    if (value != null)
    {
        if (value.Equals(expectedValue))
        {
            button.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            button.Checked = false;
        }
    }       
}
```

The issue as to why it loses the formatting is not obvious, to me.
I suspect it lies within one of these two but perhaps I'm mistaken or I'm misunderstanding something. Any pointers would be most appreciated. Thanks.

---

Edit: 2014-06-18

New snippet:

```
private void UpdateButtonsStateWithSelection()
{
    TextRange range = new TextRange(_SpellBox.CaretPosition, _SpellBox.CaretPosition);
    if (range != null)
    {
        UpdateAllButtonsCheckedState();
    }   
}
```

It is rather counterintuitive, for me, that the text range needed for the state update is only CaretPosition.

Comment: I came across a post from October 2008, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202434/get-fontweight-fontstyle-textdecorations-from-wpf-richtextbox), and I think this implementation, so far, seems to resolve my problem. I've replaced the contents of the UpdateButtonStateWithSelection method, with that of the snippet provided by Donnelle.