# How to check if text in a RichTextBox is underlined?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently programming a text editor with WPF that contains a tool bar and a RichTextBox. Each Button in the tool bar defines the text properties that will be applied to the selected text (using costum properties). It works fine.

#### Problem

If the user clicks somewhere on the text the buttons should be highlighted if their text property is applied to the current position. When I try to check if the current selection is underlined/strikethrought or not, it's not working.

#### Code

```
private void checkToolBarButtons()
    {
        // this method checks if the button should be highlighted or not.
        Func<Button, object> check = (Button button) =>
        {
            try
            {
                // the button has two costum properties that allow to determine which text property should be
                // applied to the selected text.
                string propString = ToolBarButton.GetDocumentProperty(button);
                // e.g. "TextDecorations"
                DependencyProperty dependency = this.getPropertyByString(propString);
                // e.g. TextDecorationsProperty
                string propertyValue = ToolBarButton.GetDocumentPropertyValue(button);
                // e.g. "Underline"

                if (dependency != null)
                {
                    TextRange selectionRange = new TextRange(this.richTextBox.Selection.Start, this.richTextBox.Selection.End);
                    object selectedProperty = selectionRange.GetPropertyValue(dependency);

                    if (selectedProperty.GetType() == typeof(TextDecorationCollection) && ((TextDecorationCollection)selectedProperty).Count > 0)
                    {
                        if (selectedProperty.Equals(TextDecorations.Underline))
                        {
                            // this code is never reached 
                            selectedProperty = "Underline";
                        }
                        else if (selectedProperty.Equals(TextDecorations.Strikethrough))
                        {
                            // this code is never reached 
                            selectedProperty = "Strikethrough";
                        }
                    }

                    if (selectedProperty.ToString() == propertyValue)
                    {
                        button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return null;
        };

        foreach (FrameworkElement ctrl in toolBar.Children)
        {
            if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(StackPanel))
            {
                foreach (Button button in ((Panel)ctrl).Children)
                {
                    check(button);
                }
            }
            else if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(Button))
            {
                check((Button)ctrl);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// converts a string to a DependencyProperty
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyString"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private DependencyProperty getPropertyByString(string propertyString)
    {
        switch (propertyString)
        {
            case ("FontStyleProperty"): return FontStyleProperty;
            case ("FontWeightProperty"): return FontWeightProperty;
            case ("TextDecorations"): return TextBlock.TextDecorationsProperty;
            case ("TextAlignment"): return TextBlock.TextAlignmentProperty;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

#### XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="EasyControls.TextEditor"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EasyControls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" Height="236.318" Width="493.571">
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Blue">
    <DockPanel Background="White">
        <WrapPanel x:Name="toolBar" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#FF2B2B8F" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <StackPanel x:Name="textAlignPanel"  Background="#FFF4F4F5" Height="21" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
                <Button local:ToolBarButton.DocumentProperty="TextAlignment" local:ToolBarButton.DocumentPropertyValue="Left"
                         Margin="2 2 2 2" Click="ToolBarButton_Click" Width="20">
                    <Image Source="img/Left.png" />
                </Button>
                <Button local:ToolBarButton.DocumentProperty="TextAlignment" local:ToolBarButton.DocumentPropertyValue="Center"
                         Margin="2 2 2 2" Click="ToolBarButton_Click" Width="20">
                    <Image Source="img/Center.png" />
                </Button>
                <Button local:ToolBarButton.DocumentProperty="TextAlignment" local:ToolBarButton.DocumentPropertyValue="Right"
                         Margin="2 2 2 2" Click="ToolBarButton_Click" Width="20">
                    <Image Source="img/Right.png" />
                </Button>
                <Button local:ToolBarButton.DocumentProperty="TextAlignment" local:ToolBarButton.DocumentPropertyValue="Justify"
                         Margin="2 2 2 2" Click="ToolBarButton_Click" Width="20">
                    <Image Source="img/Justify.png" />
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel x:Name="fontStylePanel"  Background="#FFF4F4F5" Height="21" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button local:ToolBarButton.DocumentProperty="FontWeightProperty" local:ToolBarButton.DocumentPropertyValue="Bold"
                         Margin="2 2 2 2" Click="ToolBarButton_Click" FontWeight="Bold" Width="20">
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">b</TextBlock>
                </Button>
                <Button local:ToolBarButton.DocumentProperty="FontStyleProperty" local:ToolBarButton.DocumentPropertyValue="Italic"
                         Margin="1 2 2 2" Click="ToolBarButton_Click" FontStyle="Italic" Width="20">
                    <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">i</TextBlock>
                </Button>
                <Button local:ToolBarButton.DocumentProperty="TextDecorations" local:ToolBarButton.DocumentPropertyValue="Underline"
                        Margin="1 2 2 2" Click="ToolBarButton_Click" Width="20" >
                    <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">u</TextBlock>
                </Button>
                <Button local:ToolBarButton.DocumentProperty="TextDecorations" local:ToolBarButton.DocumentPropertyValue="Strikethrough"
                        Margin="1 2 2 2" Click="ToolBarButton_Click" Width="20" >
                    <TextBlock TextDecorations="Strikethrough" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">s</TextBlock>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </WrapPanel>
        <RichTextBox x:Name="richTextBox" Background="White" SelectionChanged="RichTextBox_SelectionChanged" IsDocumentEnabled="True" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph/>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>
    </DockPanel>
</Border>
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25736503/9698068).

Comment: @geronimo678 Yeah, I made an error in reconstructing the XAML you didn't show. I had `local:ToolBarButton.DocumentProperty="FontStyleProperty"` on the Underline button rather than `local:ToolBarButton.DocumentProperty="TextDecorations"`. Once I fixed that, your code works for me just as you wrote it, as long as I call `checkToolBarButtons()` whenever the selection changes in the rich text box.

Comment: @geronimo678 Thanks for adding the XAML. You know, those attached properties could be enums btw. What's interesting to me is that `TextDecorationCollection.Equals(x)` returns true if the collection contains `x`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett you're completly right, I should use enums. The Equals() method did'nt work to me (see the my first comment to the post's answer).

Comment: @geronimo678 OK, I got it: TextDecorations.Underline is an instance of TextDecorationCollection which contains one TextDecorationLocation, `Underline`. `TextDecorations.Strikethrough` is also a collection with one item in it. When the selected text is underlined and not struck through, `selectedProperty` is actually the same object instance, so Equals() returns true and your code works (for me). If the text is underlined as well as struck through, neither of your checks is true because `selectedProperty` is a different collection, with two items in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first check whether `selectedProperty` is a `TextDecorationCollection` and then immediately after you expect it to be a `TextDecorations.Underline` or `TextDecorations.Strikethrough`? This makes no sense.

You probably want to cast `selectedProperty` to a `TextDecorationCollection` and then iterate through it. Something like this:

```
...
TextRange selectionRange = new TextRange(this.richTextBox.Selection.Start, this.richTextBox.Selection.End);
object selectedProperty = selectionRange.GetPropertyValue(TextBlock.TextDecorationsProperty);

TextDecorationCollection textDecorationCollection = selectedProperty as TextDecorationCollection;
if (textDecorationCollection != null)
{
    foreach (TextDecoration textDecoration in textDecorationCollection)
    {
        if (textDecoration.Location == TextDecorationLocation.Underline)
        {
            // this code is never reached 
            selectedProperty = "Underline";
        }
        else if (textDecoration.Location == TextDecorationLocation.Strikethrough)
        {
            // this code is never reached 
            selectedProperty = "Strikethrough";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. Iterating through the collection was the important point here. But "textDecoration.Equals(TextDecorations.Underline)" does not work, because it's not of the same type. You need to use "textDecoration.Location == TextDecorationLocation.Underline" and so on.

Comment: My mistake, I made an error in reconstructing his XAML. If DocumentProperty is "TextDecorations" and DocumentPropertyValue is "Underline", his code actually works as written, if called on RichTextBox_SelectionChanged

Comment: @EdPlunkett I'm sorry, perhaps I should have added the XAML code, too...

Comment: @geronimo678 That and the attached properties would have been helpful.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I added the XAML code, perhaps it helps other people. Next time I will add it from the beginning.